# Store words in array

Tags: java, android, arrays

I need a big list of words. So I use an array that stores four words. The problem is that I need 300+ arrays. I think my solution isn't good..

At first I store the words in the arrays like this:

```
array1 = new String[]{"Hello","Hello","Hello","Hello"};
    array2 = new String[]{"Hello","Hello","Hello","Hello"};
    array3 = new String[]{"Hello","Hello","Hello","Hello"};
    array4 = new String[]{"Hello","Hello","Hello","Hello"};
    array5 = new String[]{"Hello","Hello","Hello","Hello"};
```

Then I generate a random number that chooses an array. The switch-case will be very big and it looks like an bad solution for many arrays.

```
int random = r.nextInt((5 - 1) + 1) + 1;

    switch(random){
        case 1: array = array1; break;
        case 2: array = array2; break;
        case 3: array = array3; break;
        case 4: array = array4; break;
        case 5: array = array5; break;
    }
```

So, if I have many arrays the switch-case will be very huge and unclear. I need some ideas for a better solution.

Best regards from germany. :)

Comment: If static arrays are where you want to go, wouldn't a 2D array be a better option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better solution would be to keep an array of arrays (a 2D array, as suggested in comments by Ryan). Instead of using a switch statement, use your random variable as an index into the outer array.

One possible way to populate your arrays ...

```
int numArrays = 5;
int numElements = 4;
String[][] arrays = new String[numArrays][numElements];
for (int i=0; i<numArrays; i++)
{
    for (int j=0; j<numElements; j++)
    {
        arrays[i][j] = "Hello";
    }
}
```

To randomly get an array ...

```
int random = r.nextInt(numArrays);
String[] array = arrays[random];
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can create a map like this :

```
Map<Integer,String[]> storedArray = new HashMap<Integer,String[]>();
```

and use the key to get your arrays?

Answer (score 0):

There are two answers to your question it all depends on if you strictly need the 300+ arrays on memory or if you don´t.

In case you don´t the best option is having a big array with all your words, this can even be a thousands words array, then have a second one of the desired size and randomly filling out with words. This approach uses less memory. Your code would look somewhere like this:

```
String[] wDictionary = new String[]{"A...","n..."};
String[] wArray = new String[Array Size];

for (int j=0; j<=wArray.getSize; j++)
{
    wArray[j] = wDictionary[random];
}
```

Now, if you need the 300+ arrays initiated and loaded, you can use the approach of Rayan J. and use a bi-dimensional array. Here instead of using a switch case, you will use a random to select the array. It would be similar to selecting rows in a table with many columns filled with words.

Good luck coding!